# In Corona Sdk, I have a button in a scrollView. when touch the button. The scrollview can't be scrolled. How can I do that?

Tags: button, scrollview, coronasdk

In Corona Sdk, I have a button in a scrollView. when touch the button. The scrollview can't be scrolled. How can I do that?

The code is in the following snippet:

```
local scrollView = require("scrollView")

local background = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
background:setFillColor(100, 100, 100)



local topBoundary = display.screenOriginY
local bottomBoundary = display.screenOriginY
local scrollView = scrollView.new{ top=topBoundary, bottom=bottomBoundary }

local contentGroup = display.newGroup()
local bg = display.newImage("bg.png")
bg:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
contentGroup:insert(bg)
bg.x,bg.y = 0,0

local button = ui.newButton{
    default = "buttonBlue.png",
    over = "buttonBlueOver.png",
    text = "Button 1 Label",
    emboss = true
}
button.x, button.y = 50, 100
contentGroup:insert(button)
scrollView:insert(contentGroup)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered putting an invisible layer on top of the view that intercepts touches, making sure that it returns "true"?

Make it so that the button event listener generates this layer when pressed.

Just a thought. Best of luck. :)

-MB